# Variable in class holds wrong value

Tags: c++

I've just started learning c++, and have some earlier experience in java and c. I decided to experiment a bit with classes in order to learn more about them.

Currently I have 2 classes, *Book* and *Shelf*. Shelf consists of one Book, a string and an int. Book consists of a string and an int called *page*.

All variables contain expected values, except for my int page in *Book*. It contains some arbitrary value that seems to have no correlation to anything at all. My guess is that it has something to do with my code somehow messing up some important pointer to the page.

I've tried to change page to an *int instead of int, hoping that I would hold the pointer to the value, rather than the value itself. But the output is stil "wrong" as the dereferenced pointer still contains the wrong value.

My main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

 Book harrypotter("Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets");
 Shelf fantasy(harrypotter, "fantasy", 1);
 fantasy.getBOOK().setPAGE(15);

 std::cout << fantasy.getSUBJECT() << std::endl;
 std::cout << fantasy.getSHELFNUMBER() << std::endl;
 std::cout << fantasy.getBOOK().getNAME() << std::endl;
 std::cout << fantasy.getBOOK().getPAGE(); //this line failes

return 0;
}
```

Shelf.hpp

```
class Shelf {
public:
 Shelf();
 Shelf(Book book, std::string subject, int shelfnr);

 std::string getSUBJECT(){return this->subject;}
 Book getBOOK(){return this->book;} //container with the faulty int
 int getSHELFNUMBER(){return this->shelfnr;}

private:
 Book book;
 std::string subject;
 int shelfnr;

};
```

Book.hpp

```
class Book {
public:
 Book();
 Book(std::string name);

 std::string getNAME(){return this->name;}
 void setPAGE(int page){this->page = page;}
 int getPAGE(){return this->page;} //this returns wrong value!

private:
 std::string name;
 int page;//this contains wrong value!
};
```

Current output:

```
fantasy
1
Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets
-2145318336 (or some other arbitrary number)
```

Output that i expect:

```
fantasy
1
Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets
15
```

Comment: You might want to think a little bit about your design, having a "shelf" with only a single book doesn't make much sense (unless it's a very small shelf... ;) )

Comment: Well the whole story was to make a game in c++ until I ran into this problem. I just made this code that replicates the problem, so that you guys wouldn't have to read through the mess that is the "real" project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason why you do not see changes is this:

`Book getBOOK(){return this->book;}`

This returns a copy of the `Book` object.  Thus you are changing a copy, not the original `Book`.

If you want to change the actual `Book` object declared in `Shelf`, return a reference:

`Book& getBOOK(){return this->book;}`

Answer (score 2):

The member function `Shelf::getBOOK()` returns the data member *by value*. This means that a copy is made and returned as a temporary object. This line

```
fantasy.getBOOK().setPAGE(15);
```

mutates the temporary copy, not the object that is owned by the `Shelf` instance. The `page` variable that you access later on is hence uninitialized, and reading from it is undefined behavior. That's why it would be advantageous to set a meaningful default value, e.g.

```
class Book {
  // ...
  int page = 0;
};
```

Fixing your original issue can be achieved by

```
Book harrypotter("Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets");

harrypotter.setPage(15);

// Now, the above book has the desired state, so pass it the Shelf instance:
Shelf fantasy(harrypotter, "fantasy", 1);
```

or by changing the `Shelf::getBOOK()` signature as suggested in [@PaulMcKenzie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54344598/9593596).

Answer (score 0):

```
Book getBOOK(){return this->book;}
```

You return a copy of `book`, and call `setPAGE` on that copy. The original `book` never changes.

If there is supposed to be only one `book` in `shelf`(which is very odd) you could expose `setPAGE()` from `shelf` itself which will call `book.setPAGE()`.

If you plan to have many `book`'s on a `shelf`, `getBOOK()` doesn't make any sense.